# goto was unexpected at this time. batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I got "goto was unexpected at this time" error in my Windows batch file. It's like below. I have no idea. Anyone may help me? thanks

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
SET TEMPERL=%TMP%\perlversion.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%TEMPERL%) do (
  set line=%%a  
  if not "%line:subversion%"=="%line%" goto GETVERSION
)

:GETVERSION
set mainver=%line:*perl=%
set mainver=%mainver:~1,1%
echo This is perl %mainver%


:END
endlocal
```

Comment: don't you need `then`?

Comment: Have you tried using !variable! instead of %variable% inside FOR loop?

Comment: @DevZer0 `then` isn't needed in batch.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
SET "TEMPERL=%TMP%\perlversion.txt"
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%TEMPERL%") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not "!line:subversion=!"=="!line!" (
        set "mainver=!line:*perl=!"
        set "mainver=!mainver:~1,1!"
        echo This is Perl !mainver!
    )
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

You should *not* leave a `for` loop code block with `goto`. This makes `cmd` unstable.

You might also try this (works for strawberry Perl):

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=()" %%a in ('perl --version') do echo This is Perl %%a
for /f "tokens=4delims=(v)" %%a in ('perl --version') do echo This is Perl %%a
```

Comment: Endoro, using goto to leave a loop is a common technique - it doesn't make cmd unstable at all.

Comment: @foxidrive I don't know what's going on with the memory management of `cmd` ('stack', 'heap') if you do this. So I always try to avoid this, I never use it and never need it :) Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `goto` inside `for` is a great way (and only I know) to break cycle. Never had problems.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `FOR` loop, you'd need

```
set "line=%%a"
if not "!line:subversion=!"=="%%a" goto GETVERSION
```

OR

```
set "line=%%a"
if not "!line:subversion=!"=="%%a" goto GETVERSION
```

BECAUSE `%line%` (or any `%`var`%`) means the PARSE-TIME value of the variable, that is, as it stood BEFORE the `FOR` started executing. `!`var`!` means the RUN-TIME value of `var`, that is, as it changes during the loop - but ONLY if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has been executed (which it has in this case)

Note also the `=` before the second `!`. This introduces the replacement string in the variable - the string which replaces the target (between the `:` and the `=`), the structure thus calculating the value of `line` with any string `subversion` replaced by [nothing].

Note also that you have trailing spaces after the `%%a` in the `set line=%%a` line. Whereas what you have posted seems classically correct, the trailing spaces are INCLUDED in the value assigned, hence `%%a` and `!line!` are NOT the same thing. The enclose-the-statement-in-quotes method ensures any stray trailing spaces are not included in the string assigned. Best to use that structure - it can save a lot of head-scratching chasing invisible spaces around.

Finally, I can't guarantee that your decoding of `MAINVER` is correct, since you haven't posted the structure of the target line in `perlversion.txt`

ALSO if your target line (the one containing the string `subversion` does not exist in the file (or the file itself) is missing, you are likely to get unexpected results.